# Does Google DeepMind's Gemma 7B models specs have inconsistent dimensions?

Tags: transformer, llm, google

In Google DeepMind's Gemma technical paper (https://storage.googleapis.com/deepmind-media/gemma/gemma-report.pdf), the 7B Gemma model specs are given as d_model = 3072, num_heads = 16 and head_size = 256 for the 7B model. They don't seem consistent (16 * 256 != 3072).
Since the dimension is distributed across h heads, I think this should hold true -

```
#heads * #head_size = d_model
```

This is also explained in the original Transformers paper, "Attention Is All You Need".

This equation holds for the specs provided for Gemma 2B model in the same paper.
Am I missing something with the 7B Gemma specs? Or does this paper have an error?

Answer (score 1):

From the annotated transformer link -  https://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/annotated-transformer/#full-model
For the positionwiseFeedForward network:
D_model = 512, and the inner layer has dimensionality dff = 2048.

It’s hard to be certain but perhaps the Gemma paper is using the dff for model size. I’ve always had the same understanding as you – n_heads * size_of_head = d_model, regardless of hidden dimension. This appears to agree with the hidden_size parameter on hugging_face for gemma_7b:

•   hidden_size (int, optional, defaults to 3072) — Dimension of the hidden representations.

https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/en/model_doc/gemma